# How to mount secret as a file inside a specific non empty directory with Cloud Run second gen?

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-platform, gcp

I have this rather simple Terraform configuration for first generation cloud run service

```
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "pricing" {
  project  = var.project_id
  name     = "${var.cloud_run_service_name}-test"
  location = var.region
  ingress  = "INGRESS_TRAFFIC_INTERNAL_LOAD_BALANCER"

  traffic {
    type = "TRAFFIC_TARGET_ALLOCATION_TYPE_LATEST"
    percent = 100
  }

  template {
    execution_environment = "EXECUTION_ENVIRONMENT_GEN1"

    service_account = var.cloud_run_sa_email
    labels = {
      env     = var.environment
      service = "pricing"
    }

    scaling {
      min_instance_count = var.cloud_run_min_scale
      max_instance_count = var.cloud_run_max_scale
    }

    max_instance_request_concurrency = var.cloud_run_concurrency

    containers {
      image = var.image_url

      resources {
        limits = {
          cpu    = var.cloud_run_res_limit_cpu
          memory = var.cloud_run_res_limit_mem
        }
        cpu_idle = true
        startup_cpu_boost = true
      }

      volume_mounts {
        name       = "dotenv"
        mount_path = "/var/www/.env.prod.local"
      }
      env {
        name  = "HOSTNAME"
        value = var.hostname
      }
      env {
        name  = "GCP_LB_IP"
        value = var.gcp_lb_ip
      }
    }

    volumes {
      name = "dotenv"
      secret {
        secret = var.dotenv_file_secret_id
        items {
          version  = "latest"
          path = "."
        }
      }
    }

    vpc_access{
      connector = var.vpc_connector_id
      egress = "ALL_TRAFFIC"
    }
  }
}
```

All works fine with first generation runtime but breaks when I want to use second generation. I suppose it is because secrets are not mounted correctly:

```
terminated: Application failed to start: volumefs(0, secret_volume_0): bind mounting from /var/lib/volumes/secret/secret_volume_0: mount(/mnt/app/0/var/www/.env.prod.local): not a directory
```

I first generation I was able to mount secret as a regular file under `/var/www/.env.prod.local` but the same fail in second generation. How can I make it work same way in second generation?